# Gateway Pattern using Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I am using the gateway pattern in a Java EE project at which I have:

> A stateful session bean with extended presistence context.
>
> The bean has transaction attribute set to not supported in order to
>   stop any transaction to be commited into the database.
>
> The bean has a save method with transaction attribute set to require
>   new which will lead to a new transaction that will commit all the
>   changes of the entity and reflects them to the database.

see Gateway: [adam bein page-67](http://download.java.net/general/podcasts/real_world_java_ee_patterns.pdf)

Until two days ago I was using GlassFish 3 and all worked normally. I retrieve an entity, make changes, then call the save method without merging the entity. The entity changes are flushed to the database. But when I changed GlassFish to GlassFish 4 this operation stopped, and now I have to merge the entity in order to flush the changed entity to the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gateway pattern and glassfish4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349469/gateway-pattern-and-glassfish4)

Answer (score 1):

Save specifically does an insert. So calling save again will result in another row in the db.

Update updates an object in the session. So if the object is in the session it will update. 
If the object is not in the session, you should call merge.

So If you retrieve an entity that already exists you have to call update/merge instead of save.

[JPA specification](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317)

> The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:
>   If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new managed copy X' of X is created.
>
> If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'.
>
> If X is a removed entity instance, an  IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail).
>
> If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation, however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or  cascade=ALL annotation.
>   For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL, Y is merged recursively as Y'. For all such Y referenced by X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as X'.)
>
> If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL is not specified, then navigation of the same association from X' yields a reference to a managed object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.

Comment: I have solved this problem by the use of unsync entity manager then join transaction in the save method. i believe there was a bug in glassfish 4.0.1